not able to set the spark log properties programmatically via Python
I was trying to suppress the spark logging and specifying my own log4j.properties file.
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
--cluster test-dataproc-cluster \
--region europe-north1 \
--files  gs://test-spark-logging-bucket/log4j.properties \
--properties spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF=true,'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties,spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties' \
--class com.pythian.edp.pm.spark.job.TestSparkJob \
--jars gs://18621ad39476e29c-test-static/spark-jobs/sparkBigQueryConnector/spark-bigquery-assembly-0.11.1-beta-SNAPSHOT.jar,gs://18621ad39476e29c-test-static/spark-jobs/digiSparkPmCmProcessing/digiSparkPmCmProcessing-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
-- --configurationURI gs://18621ad39476e29c-test-static/spark-job-configs/f9fabc4f-162e-40f3-af69-237e4c464c9e-PM-LTE-CELLCQI/ing-15min-cell-1719203688539.yml \
--jobType "ingestion" --dataType "PM" \
--sendPubSubNotification --pubSubProjectId bmas-eu-digi-pipe-uat --pubSubTopicName data-notifications \
--traceDatasets > test_log_ingestion_job_log 2>&1

above command is working fine but I am struggling to set it via python code.
below is the snippet of the code I am working with.
   job_properties.update(
            {"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled":"true",
             "spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors" : "0",
             "spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors" : "5",
             "spark.executor.instances": "0",
             "spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF":"true",
             "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions":"-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties",
             "spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF":"-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties"
             })
    # log_file_location='gs://test-spark-logging-bucket/log4j.properties'
    job_details = {
        'placement': {
            'cluster_name': cluster_name,
        },
        'reference': {
            'job_id': job_id,
        },
        'scheduling': {
            'max_failures_per_hour': 1,
        },
        'labels': labels,
        'spark_job': {
            'args': spark_job_arguments,
            'main_class': SPARK_JOB_CLASSNAME,
            'jar_file_uris': [
                os.path.join(self.dataproc_job_jar_file_prefix, file) for file in jar_files
            ],
            'properties': job_properties,
        }
    }


Are you using the Dataproc_v1 library to submit the job?


I assume you meant to set spark.executor.extraJavaOptions instead of this:


"spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF":"-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties"


log4j.properties file needs to be made physically available on driver/executor nodes of the cluster. In CLI invocation (gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark) you're doing this using --files gs://test-spark-logging-bucket/log4j.properties. You need to do something similar while invoking using python. It would depend on what API you're using (AirFlow/google.cloud/...). Post rest of your python code.

Have you tried providing logging_config as part of job details? Not sure if this is applicable only to driver (as the name suggests) or both driver and executor.


job_details = {
    'placement': {
        'cluster_name': cluster_name,
    },
    'reference': {
        'job_id': job_id,
    },
    'scheduling': {
        'max_failures_per_hour': 1,
    },
    'labels': labels,
    'spark_job': {
        'args': spark_job_arguments,
        'main_class': SPARK_JOB_CLASSNAME,
        'jar_file_uris': [
            os.path.join(self.dataproc_job_jar_file_prefix, file) for file in jar_files
        ],
        'properties': job_properties,
        'logging_config': {
            'driver_log_levels': {
                'org.apache': 'OFF'
            }
        }
    }
}

